# pyqt6 WindowContextHelpButtonHint

Tags: pyqt6

In PyQt5 I use this code to hide the Windows Dialog help question mark. I cannot find an equivalent flag in PyQt6.

```
self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint)
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved, its namespace is:

```
Qt.WindowType.WindowContextHelpButtonHint
```